# Python [Errno 98]:address is already in use

Tags: python, server, client

I am using Ubuntu in virtual machine ,i have tried to kill the process but still showing the same error.

Comment: Thanks! but i figured it out that we just have to close that terminal in which server is running on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very common error. It happens because you don't dispose the server properly.

A naive solution is to switch port and wait for ~15 minutes. Then the first port you tried to use will be free.

Also I'd recommend you to stop using ^C / killing Python process to stop the server, because server is not disposed in this case.